# Is there a way to remove questions closed from my feed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, frontpage

On the front page of MSE, I often see a large number of closed questions. Is there a way to make the front page show only questions which are still open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search `closed:no` and select the appropriate tab.